# waterline-model.create - primaryKey

Tags: database, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have below model with primary key id:

```
attributes: {
   id: {
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true
   },
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true,
      required: true
   },
}
```

I am creating model as below:

```
var model = {
     id: undefined,
     name: 'name',
};
```

**waterlinemodel.create(model).exec(function(error, result) {});**

But it throws below error:
**Error (E_UNKNOWN) Encountered an unexpected error] Details: error: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint**

**As, 'id' is a primary key, waterline should not look at what is the value of 'id' property.**

How to resolve this error? I do not want to remove 'id' because I have created value object for the model and it contains all the attributes of model.I am setting value object property as I need. I do not need to set id property for creation.

Comment: If you do not need to set the id property, or have no reason why you want to assign your own primary key id, why do you do so? The primary key will be assigned automatically if not explicitly told not to do so. Removing the "id: undefined" will probably just work.

Comment: According to java script. If I do not define id or i assign value as undefine both are same. Still waterline gives error.

Comment: With autoPK = true? According to your response below autoPK is false, and as of such you will have to supply a valid id. If you set autoPK to true you shouldn't have to define one (you can omit the id property).

Answer (score 1):

I am having exactly the same problem especially with the model configured to use postgresql. With it set to disk or memory, the resource is created but with postgresql the resource is not created with the not null constraint error.

The id is not being set irrespective of whether I set `autoPK: true` or not. Even setting the id attribute on the model with `autoPK:false` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says :

```
Will set the primary key of the record. This should be used when autoPK is set to false.

attributes: {
  uuid: {
    type: 'string',
    primaryKey: true,
    required: true
  }
}
```

You need to set `autoPK : false` on your model.

The link to the doc : https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models.md#primarykey

Comment: Reading the question and judging by the quality of it I think he has no intention to set his own primary key. From what I read he should keep autoPK set to true and simply remove the id: undefined to let the system generate his primary key.

Comment: So it have to remove primaryKey:true too

Comment: Did you try to totally remove id: undefined ? Like var model = {
     name: 'name'
};

Comment: That is the question, I do not want to remove  id: undefined, from model.

Answer (score 0):

## 2019 Answer

`jaumard`'s link to documentation is coming up with a 404 error now, but I think things may have changed since 2015...

Sails.js has base attributes defined in `config/models.js` which looks something this in a freshly-generated project:

```
attributes: {
  createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true, },
  updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true, },
  id: { type: 'number', autoIncrement: true, },
}
```

Separately, the default `primaryKey` is set to `id`. If you wanted to override that, you would need to explicitly specify your new `primaryKey` in your full model definition. For example, if you wanted to make `name` your `primaryKey` you would use something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  primaryKey: 'name',
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },
    // ...
  },
}
```

Notice I put `primaryKey` outside `attributes`. This is important. Your `primaryKey` will also need the `unique` and `required` constraints.

Further, if you want to disable the `id` column so it is not committed to your database, you must replace `id` with the value `false` -- but then you **must** define a different `primaryKey` otherwise you will get an error when you start your application. The error shown in the question may be directly related to the fact that the model defined `id` explicitly as `undefined`. An example of how to disable `id` would look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  primaryKey: 'name',
  attributes: {
    id: false,
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },
    // ...
  },
}
```